# Hibernate 4: How do I resolve a "An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping" exception?

Tags: hibernate, configuration

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.5.SP1, but having trouble configuring a session factory for use with my annotation-based classes.  I try and configure it with

```
    final Configuration hibConfiguration = new Configuration().configure();       

    final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(hibConfiguration.getProperties())
        .buildServiceRegistry();

    return hibConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

But I get this exception ("An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.UserRole"/>]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:214)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
* Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) ---------------
```

javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use 
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:87)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:130)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:195)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.localInvoke(MessagingContainer.java:249)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.delivery(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:268)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.invoke(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:138)
        at $Proxy128.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.quartz.inflow.QuartzJob.execute(QuartzJob.java:57)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use 
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1600)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1555)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1534)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1508)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
        at org.subco.myco.dido.service.AbstractServiceProvider.getSessionFactory(AbstractServiceProvider.java:64)
        at org.subco.myco.dido.service.AbstractServiceProvider.initServices(AbstractServiceProvider.java:127)
        at org.subco.myco.dido.quartz.ProcessOrdersJob.execute(ProcessOrdersJob.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
        ... 11 more

Here are my Maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file …

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.datasource">MySqlDS</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.UserRole" />
        <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.Organization" />
        <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.Product" />
        <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.State" />
        <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.Country" />
        <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.AccessCode" />
        <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.Contract" />
        <mapping class="com.mainco.fdr.myproject.model.TrainingLink" /> 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm replying my application as a JAR file to a JBoss 4.2.2.GA server (don't have control over JBoss version).  What are the proper dependencies I should include and what is the right way to configure my session factory so that I can read annotation-based classes, like the one below …

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lyc_user_role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ROLE_ID")
    private String roleId;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem you are actually not using the Hibernate version 4.1.5.SP1 you think you are using.  In fact that exception message was removed from Hibernate completely in 3.6 when we merged annotations (and their processing) into the hibernate-core module.  Probably you need to look around in JBoss lib directories and you will find the older Hibernate jars that are causing the problem.  I do not remember back all the way to JBoss 4 to be able to tell you where to look.

Comment: I'm still trying to find the rogue file, but am I to take it from your post that unless you alter the JBoss 4 configuration, it's impossible to deploy a Hibernate 4 application?

Comment: JBoss 4 still worked on its older "unified classloader" (UCL) concept.  That is what you are fighting here.  The other option is to create your deployment with scoped classloading where the jars in your deployment take precedence over those already present in the UCL.  I forget how that is done in JBoss 4 however.